# Unable to understand this strange MySql client behavior

Tags: mysql, client

I'm not sure what's going on here with the line art output by /usr/bin/mysql here.

**The problem:** I'm unable to redirect the line art (used in creating the table columns) to a file!

First, I do this on my terminal.

```
[sd@host:~/tmp]
$ mysql -usd sd -e 'select * from loan;'
+---------+--------------+--------+
| loan_no | branch_name  | amount |
+---------+--------------+--------+
| L-11    | Round Hill   |    900 | 
| L-14    | Downtown     |   1500 | 
| L-15    | Perryridge   |   1500 | 
| L-16    | Perryridge   |   1300 | 
| L-17    | Downtown     |   1000 | 
| L-23    | Redwood      |   2000 | 
| L-93    | Mianus       |    500 | 
+---------+--------------+--------+
```

Now, I want this whole blessed thing printed above captured, so I redirect stdout and stderr to the file 'out', like so:

```
[sd@host:~/tmp]
$ mysql -usd sd -e 'select * from loan;' >out 2>&1
```

As you can see below, the line art is completely missing!

```
[sd@host:~/tmp]
$ cat out
loan_no branch_name amount
L-11    Round Hill  900
L-14    Downtown    1500
L-15    Perryridge  1500
L-16    Perryridge  1300
L-17    Downtown    1000
L-23    Redwood 2000
L-93    Mianus  500
```

More proof that the line art is REALLY missing! (The -T option prints tabs, if any.)

```
[sd@host:~/tmp]
$ cat -T out
loan_no^Ibranch_name^Iamount
L-11^IRound Hill^I900
L-14^IDowntown^I1500
L-15^IPerryridge^I1500
L-16^IPerryridge^I1300
L-17^IDowntown^I1000
L-23^IRedwood^I2000
L-93^IMianus^I500
```

So, **my question is**, how the heck does mysql know **who** -- whether a terminal or a text file -- **is sucking its output from 'its rear end'** :-) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Program can determine whether output stream is terminal or 
not using [isatty (3) function](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/isatty/).

MySQL uses this information to change its output (see [man mysql](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/mysql/), "-t" option produces table output for non-interactive mode too)

Comment: Thanks Peter. 
Upvoting a +1 to you.

Answer (score 2):

It *knows*

The situation is analogous to

```
$ ls
tom   dick   harry
```

and

```
$ ls > out
$ cat out
tom
dick
harry
```

Comment: Thanks, pavium.
Upvoting a +1 to you.